# Google Oauth2 Playground to Php

Tags: php, oauth2-playground

In Oauth2 playground I have set it up to use my oauth client id and secret with the Google Play Game Services v1 and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games scope.

I then exchange the Auth code retrieved from unity google play login to get an access code and then use [https://games.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/{applicationId}/verify](https://games.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/%7BapplicationId%7D/verify) which successfully gives me the players google play id.

The problem I am having is knowing the php required with the google api to do this in the php part. Right now I have the following but not sure if it is correct or where to go from here, Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
require_once("google/vendor/autoload.php");
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=secret.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games');
$service = new Google_Service_Games($client);
```

Comment: You question is how to exchange the code received after the user logs in to your app, for a token? https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/v2.13.0/Google_Client.html#method_fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode

Comment: I tried that one with the following and it always returns 
array(2) { ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_grant" ["error_description"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" }

`$authtoken = 'tokenstringhere'; $client = new Google_Client(); 
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials(); 
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/games'); 
$client->setAccessType('offline');  
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authtoken); 
echo "token ".var_dump($token);`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here, you want to log the user into your game, yes? Then you need to get a _code_ first, that is what you exchange for a token (not another, already existing token.) And to get the code, you need to send them to the login URL first (method `createAuthUrl`.)

Comment: The user logs into unity android game with google play and gets the auth code, I then want to send that auth code to my php server and use it to get their google play id.